# I created a custom token in my wallet and sent tokens to it after the didn't show up I I put wrong decibel can it be fixed?

Tags: decimals

Trust wallet etherscan shows coins to bi in my wallet with the rest of my coins
But wallet shows no coins for the one I made custom token I put 12 decibel instead of 9 how can I fix this?

Comment: It will not show-up automatically you have to add custom on top lept of all coins page

Comment: Decibel ? Do you mean decimal ?